# Is there a $\tau$ topology for which $B$ is the base?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Please check if this is correct. $X = \{a,b,c,d,e \}$

1. $B = \{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,c\}\{a,b,d\}\}$ — no because set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ can't be created.
2. $B = \{\{a\},\{b\},\{a,c\},\{b,d\},\{b,e\}\}$ — no because set $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ cant be created.
3. $B = \{\{a\},\{b\},\{e\},\{a,c\},\{b,c,d\}\}$ — yes, and topology is: $\tau = \{\{\emptyset\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{d\},\{e\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d,e\}\}$

Answer (score 3):

1. That is not correct. It is not a base because $X$ is not an union of elements of that set.
2. That is not correct. That set is a base of the topology$$\bigl\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,c\},\{b,d\},\{b,e\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,e\},\{a,b,d\},\{a,b,c\},\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,e\},X\bigr\}.$$
3. It is also not correct. It is not a base because $\{a,c\}\cap\{b,c,d\}=\{c\}$ and no element of $B$ to which $c$ belongs is a subset of $\{c\}$.